# GWT war file uses old source files

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, ant, war

I am using Ant builder and Eclipse to create a war file of my GWT project for deployment on Tomcat (on a windows 7 machine).
I am following the following [easy tutorial](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/) to the letter.

Unfortunately after deploying to Tomcat I discovered that it has been using the old source files.

I tried the following solutions:

- I re-exported the src jar file.
- I did Clean Project.
- I deleted the war file and jar file and rerun the script several times.
- I deployed and undeployed from Tomcat more than a couple of times.
- Tomcat was a fresh install and thus it did not have the original war file in the past.

I am not very knowledgeable about Ant nor Tomcat.

Comment: Not exactly related to GWT. I am guessing you are missing some ant build command relating to cleanup of old build. If you are new to ant then you might as well go with maven. GWT team has excellent tutorial w.r.t to working with maven and has sample projects. http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples%2Fdynatablerf

Comment: @Andrei Volgin - Thank you for the time spent on correcting spelling and case. I must say that I did not see the words "Thank You" to be offensive, obtrusive or too bit consuming for the Stackoverflow servers to handle.

Comment: I still think it is my prerogative.  Please try not to censor other people.